# Pashto Script in Latex

Tags: arabic

I would like to know, how to include Pastho-Script in my document.
A similar question was asked here before, but only concering the use of one single charakter in the document, while I would like to include complete sentences.
The thing is, that within the \begin{RL} \end{RL} environment my compiler claims the command "\textpashto" is "illegal".
How to pair these?
The code is:

```
\begin{RL}
\textpashto{دی په هامبورګ کې دئ}
\end{RL}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's really hard to help you if you just post a fragment of code. Instead, edit your question to include a small compilable document that can reproduce the problem you're having. Since you're getting an error it's good if the document produces the error and then we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Here's an example of using Pashto in a document: [LuaLatex: Language 'Pashto' not available for font(fontspec) 'Amiri-Regular' with script 'Arabic'](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/572933)

Comment: Which engine are you using? If you are open to use LuaLaTeX, then it has amazing support for RTL languages these days.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sorry, really I'm not aware of `pashto` refers a `language`, sincere apologies

Answer (score 4):

It’s strongly recommended `xetex` or `luatex`. My personal choice is the latter and here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=default, english]{babel}
\babelfont[pashto]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

English \foreignlanguage{pashto}{دی په هامبورګ کې دئ} English

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used [AwamiNastaliq](https://software.sil.org/awami/download/) for printing Pashto:

[image: 1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\psfnt[Renderer={Harfbuzz}]{AwamiNastaliq-Regular.ttf}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\pstxt{\psfnt}

\begin{document}
This is some English text followed by Pashto text \pstxt{دی په هامبورګ کې دئ}.
\end{document}
```

I used LuaLaTeX for producing this. Note that the Pashto characters are automatically understood to be printed RTL. This is done by `bidi=basic` parameter to `babel`. You don't even need to set or change the language with this approach. Your font-command interprets and prints the input correctly.